# CSS :before pseudo element not showing up for one h1

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know there are other questions relating to this. But I am unable to make the answers to those work. I have 3 different pages, on each I have an `h1` element that has a styled `:before` pseudo element. On two of the pages, the `h1:before` works just fine, but on the last it does not show up in the DOM at all.

```
//mixin
@mixin pageHeading($left, $bottom, $width) {
  content: "";
  left: $left;
  bottom: $bottom;
  width: $width;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #38495a !important;
}


//WORKING
//styles
.projects {
   #heading {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
      @include pageHeading(40%, -0.2em, 20%);
    }
  }
}
//html
<div className='container projects d-flex flex-column'>
      <h1 className='mt-3 mb-5' id='heading'>Projects</h1>

//NOT WORKING
//stlyes
.contact {
   #heading {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
      @include pageHeading(40%, -0.2em, 20%);
    }
  }
}
//html
<div className='container d-flex flex-column contact'>
      <h1 className='mt-3 mb-5' id='heading'>Contact Me</h1>
```

Comment: that's weird, is the `position: relative` style being applied to `.contact #heading` ?

Comment: @TomFinney it's being applied to the #heading in each case.

Comment: This may not be the issue, but do these `heading` elements appear on the same page? Since `ids` need to be unique, that *may* be causing an issue - other than that, the CSS/SCSS looks fine. Is there a typo somewhere for the `contact` element?

Comment: @disinfor I can't see any typo, I copied and pasted the code. There's only the one `#heading` for each page.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like for that page? Is there another CSS rule that's overriding the pseudo element? Since what you posted here would technically work, there might be something else in code that's altering that specific h1.

Comment: Is there some rule that would cause the `:before` pseudo element to not even show in the DOM?